# Is there a mathematical definition of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

First of all, I apologize if this question is inappropriate for math SE. In mathematics textbooks, there are defined all sorts of things, like groups, fields, boolean algebras, turing machines, etc. However, there is no definition of mathematics itself. I know some dictionaries define math as the study of this or that, but that is simply the study of math, not math itself. So, what is a mathematical definition of mathematics? Is there even such a thing at all?

Comment: Bertrand Russell pinned it down pretty well in *Mysticism and Logic*:  "Mathematics may be defined as the subject in which we never know what we are talking about, nor whether what we are saying is true."

Comment: There's no mathematical definition of math.  There's various English dictionary definitions, though. The one I prefer is: the study of well-defined, abstract systems.

Comment: Why would “mathematics” have a definition like a definition of “groups”? I guess you could say something like: mathematics is the rigorous study of patterns and structure, but I don’t see how you could pin this down to an axiomatic definition- although perhaps there is a way.

Comment: There's a mathematical definition of "axiomatic system", which is the apparatus you're formally using when you study a particular subject: the language you need to build statements about the objects, along with axioms for what's true of those objects by assumption, and logical rules for deducing new statements from old ones. There are (multiple) axiomatic systems for each of the example subjects you gave: groups, fields, etc. and for plenty of other things besides. Axiomatic systems are studied as mathematical objects in their own right in areas of logic such as proof theory and model theory.

Comment: I'd add that my comment doesn't contradict what others have said here: defining axiomatic systems is fairly easy and studying them is fruitful, but that doesn't tell us much about what maths "is", or e.g. what mathematicians in general do. Most of us don't actually work within formal systems, the ones we choose to study are not arbitrary, but none of that is, or perhaps can be, fully formalized.

Comment: Any definition ought to be big enough to encompass many forms of math, not just the modern concept of math.  The ancient Babylonians and so on surely knew math even if they didn't have axiomatic systems.

Comment: @JairTaylor: I agree. I simply meant that maths studies things which can be formally described (even if we don't always reason in terms of formal descriptions), and so inasmuch as the subject can be used to study itself, the appropriate formal objects are axiomatic systems. I feel this may be the closest thing in spirit to what the question is asking about.

Comment: @RobinSaunders I was not disagreeing with you. (actually I upvoted your second comment.)

Comment: This feels like asking for a chemical definition of chemistry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in the paper "[On Proof and Progress in Mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404236)" by Bill Thurston, in particular the recursive definition of mathematics given on page 2. Here is the relevant passage:

> It may sound almost circular to say that what mathematicians are accomplishing is to advance human understanding of mathematics. I will not try to resolve this by discussing what mathematics is, because it would take us far afield. Mathematicians generally feel that they know what mathematics is, but find it difficult to give a good direct definition. It is interesting to try. For me, "the theory of formal patterns" has come the closest, but to discuss this would be a whole essay in itself.
>
> Could the difficulty in giving a good direct definition of mathematics be an
> essential one, indicating that mathematics has an essential recursive quality? Along
> these lines we might say that mathematics is the smallest subject satisfying the
> following:
>
> - Mathematics includes the natural numbers and plane and solid geometry.
> - Mathematics is that which mathematicians study.
> - Mathematicians are those humans who advance human understanding of
>   mathematics.
>
> In other words, as mathematics advances, we incorporate it into our thinking. As
> our thinking becomes more sophisticated, we generate new mathematical concepts
> and new mathematical structures: the subject matter of mathematics changes to
> reflect how we think.

This definition appeals to me, but like any recursive definition, it is "bottom up", so its extent is not so obvious. Here is an alternative (the phrasing is mine, but the idea is hardly original to me):

> Mathematics is the domain of inquiry where logical reasoning is the sole methodology. That is, a question is a mathematical question if and only if it can (in principle) be settled by logical reasoning alone.

Answer (score 0):

This is mix of a non-anwser and a answer, hope is useful.

Mathematics is a human pratice as the kinds of art, engineering, philosophy ans so on, and as such it doesn't actually have a extremely well define and definitive definition. It has a tradition, with names, method's, masters,books, morals and so on, which would led us to the definition that mathematics is what mathematician's does.

Another point is that defining mathematics is kind outside mathematics itself, would probably be in philosophy. And as for what i know, mathematics don't define or have real definitions for things outside numbers, algebra, geometry and other abstract concepts.

One possible answer that you mind find interesting is that modern mathematics is set up in the context of set theory and logic. So you could define some form of "formal mathematics" as a system that includes these both theories (maybe considering mathematics as [formal Firs-Order Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories)) and as a consequence would get something similar to a definition, i think. But it wouldn't be that real or useful or insightful anyway. There is the obvious case os [meta-mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics) but it's more about studying the method's, proofs and logic of mathematics than asking "what is?" or "how to define mathematics?".

In the end the answer is more a no, but it's a interesting question go think about.